# What is this white fungus on my oak tree?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, fungus, oak, mold

This white material is on my oak tree, and it's appeared within the last month. What is it, how can I treat it, and is it contagious (it's begun to fall from the tall oak tree onto surrounding plants)?

I live in Florida.

[A closeup of the tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbsTP.jpg), [a long shot of the tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEXGm.jpg), and a [closeup of a fallen leaf covered in the fungus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyaLK.jpg).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it might be Woolly Aphid, specifically Woolly Oak Aphid, especially as you're in Florida. The only thing I'm not sure of is I can't find anything that says this particular form of woolly aphid affects the woody parts of the tree; other forms of woolly aphid do so, coating branches with layers of what looks like white fluff or fur. Whilst a bit technical, this link here [woolly oak aphids](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/TREES/woolly_oak_aphid.htm), lower down under Control, suggests contacting Florida University extension office to decide if it needs treating and what to do about it - with most forms of woolly aphid, spraying the branches with the hose is enough to dislodge it, but this form affects the leaves of course. They may also be able to help regarding whether or not it forms deposits on woody parts of the tree as well as the leaves.

I do have one other reservation though - the fallen leaf covered in fungus does not look like an oak leaf, unless its shape is somewhat obscured.

Comment: NO KIDDING!!  Maybe the second photo MIGHT have oak leaves but shoot sure doesn't look like an oak.  Too many tiny branches at wrong angles to the trunk/main stems.  My goodness.  I can't see the WHITE STUFF on any of the pictures except this leaf that is not an oak. I am having a difficult time seeing this tree covered in white fungal mycelium...I am at a loss.  Just judging the color of the tree by the green plant in the foreground makes this tree look very very sick or dead..  Whoa.  Yup contacting the extension service is your best next move...gross!!

Comment: @stormy Probably some type of live oak.

Comment: @DebbieM. ah, yes, Quercus virginiana - that would fit with the leaf shape too. I've never actually seen one, being in the UK.